# JavaScript how to sort date by most recent first

Tags: javascript, json, sorting, date, datetime

I am trying to sort JSON objects received from an API so that the most recent datetime is shown first. But the way I am currently doing it is sorting Dec 2022 as more recent than Jan 2023.

Here is what I'm working with currently:

```js
result = [
{
   "date": "21/12/2022",
    "time": "10:41:10",
},
{
    "date": "20/12/2022",
    "time": "12:42:21",
},
{
    "date": "15/12/2022",
    "time": "09:26:02",
},
{
    "date": "14/12/2022",
    "time": "10:20:54",
},
{
    "date": "09/01/2023",
    "time": "18:58:17",
},
{
    "date": "09/01/2023",
    "time": "18:57:34",
},  
{
    "date": "08/01/2023",
    "time": "12:12:38",
}]

if (result.length > 1) {
        result.sort((a, b) => {
            const dateTime1 = new Date(a.date + a.time);
            const dateTime2 = new Date(b.date + b.time);

            return dateTime2 - dateTime1;
        });

        console.log(result);
};
```

Which gives me:

```
{date: "21/12/2022", time: "10:41:10...}
{date: "20/12/2022", time: "12:42:21...}
{date: "15/12/2022", time: "09:26:02...}
{date: "14/12/2022", time: "10:20:54...}
{date: "09/01/2023", time: "18:58:17...}
{date: "09/01/2023", time: "18:57:34...}
{date: "08/01/2023", time: "12:12:38...}
```

How can I sort this in a way that it doesn't think 2022 is more recent than 2023?

Comment: Add a space to Date constructor `new Date(a.date + " " + a.time)`

Comment: @JanPfeifer It will still not work as JS does not accept "DD/MM/YYYY" in constructor

Comment: True, its "MM/DD/YYY". You need to parse it. See other answer.

Comment: @Rajesh—that depends. Parsing of unsupported formats is implementation dependent, so d/m/y is possible. Bottom line is don't use the built–in parser for unsupported formats.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue with your code is date creation.

You can use following snippet to create date as date constructor does not accept DD/MM/YYYY.

```
const createDate = (d, t) => {
  const [date, month, year] = d.split('/')
  const [hours, mins, secs] = t.split(':')
  return new Date(year, month - 1, date, hours, mins, secs)
}
```

Also, `a.date + a.time` is incorrect. You are concatinating both but without space. So following will be the output:

> Date: "21/12/2022"
> Time: "10:41:10" 
> Output: "21/12/202210:41:10"

**Following is a working example**

```js
result = [{
    "date": "21/12/2022",
    "time": "10:41:10",
  },
  {
    "date": "20/12/2022",
    "time": "12:42:21",
  },
  {
    "date": "15/12/2022",
    "time": "09:26:02",
  },
  {
    "date": "14/12/2022",
    "time": "10:20:54",
  },
  {
    "date": "09/01/2023",
    "time": "18:58:17",
  },
  {
    "date": "09/01/2023",
    "time": "18:57:34",
  },
  {
    "date": "08/01/2023",
    "time": "12:12:38",
  }
]

const createDate = (d, t) => {
  const [date, month, year] = d.split('/')
  const [hours, mins, secs] = t.split(':')
  return new Date(year, month - 1, date, hours, mins, secs)
}

if (result.length > 1) {
  result.sort((a, b) => {
    const dateTime1 = createDate(a.date, a.time);
    const dateTime2 = createDate(b.date, b.time);
    return dateTime2 - dateTime1;
  });

  console.log(result);
};
```

---

As correctly mentioned by @[RobG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/257182/robg)

> That should be new Date(year, month - 1, date, hours, mins, secs), but for sorting it won't matter if all months are +1.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your `date` and `time` in `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` format and then lexicographically sort it.

```js
const arr = [ { "date": "21/12/2022", "time": "10:41:10", }, { "date": "20/12/2022", "time": "12:42:21", }, { "date": "15/12/2022", "time": "09:26:02", }, { "date": "14/12/2022", "time": "10:20:54", }, { "date": "09/01/2023", "time": "18:58:17", }, { "date": "09/01/2023","time": "18:57:34", }, { "date": "08/01/2023", "time": "12:12:38", }],
    sorted = arr.map(o => [o, o.date.split('/').reverse().join('-') + '_' + o.time])
               .sort((a, b) => b[1].localeCompare(a[1]))
               .map(([o]) => o);
console.log(sorted);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```